# How to get text between two patterns in awk?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

Giving this input.txt:

```
START asd
blah
blah
blah

START HELLO
lorem
ipsum
dolor 
sit
amet

START STACK
bleh
bleh
```

I'm trying to get the lines between `START HELLO` and `START STACK`.

So this is the **desired output**:

```
START HELLO
lorem
ipsum
dolor 
sit
amet
```

---

I did this awk:

```
awk '/START/{l++} {if(l==2){exit;} if(l==1) {print}}' input.txt
```

But returns the first START block, not the `START HELLO`:

```
START asd
blah
blah
blah
```

Do you have any idea to do it as clearer as possible? I've just started with awk few days ago, so any tip, help or advided will be appreciated.

Comment: If there was another block between the `START HELLO` and `START STACK` blocks, would you want that printed too? It's important to the solution to understand if you want to stop printing because you hit `START STACK` or because you hit `START <anything>` or because you hit a blank line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blank lines are handy: you can use "paragraph" mode where each awk record is separated by blank lines instead of newlines:

```
awk -v RS="" '/^START HELLO/' file
```

If the "hello" is to be passed in as a parameter:

```
awk -v RS="" -v start=HELLO '$1 == "START" && $2 == start' file
```

Answer (score 2):

IF you need to specify between `START HELLO` and `START STACK` regardless of space paragraph:

```
awk '/START HELLO/ {f=1} /START STACK/ {f=0} f;' file
START HELLO
lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
```

It will be a more exact answer to the question: (and better if you need multiple sections)

```
I'm trying to get the lines between START HELLO and START STACK.
```

---

I would normal go for solution from Glenn, but its not true to the question

```
awk -v RS="" '/^START HELLO/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indexing is off.  Simply change your awk to:

```
awk '/START/{l++} {if(l==3){exit;} if(l==2) {print}}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the empty-line-separated block that starts with "START HELLO":

```
awk -v RS= '/^START HELLO/' file
```

To print the text between "START HELLO" and the next line that starts with "START":

```
awk '/^START HELLO{f=1} f{if (/^START/) exit; else print}' file
```

To print the text between "START HELLO" and the next line that starts with "START STACK":

```
awk '/^START HELLO{f=1} f{if (/^START STACK/) exit; else print}' file
```

If you are every considering a solution that uses `getline`, it is probably the wrong approach so make sure you read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and fully understand the appropriate uses and all of the caveats before making a decision.

Answer (score -1):

I think this maybe reach your issue:

```
awk '/START HELLO/{print;while(getline)if($0 !~/START STACK/)print;else exit}' input.txt
```

Comment: No. Absolutley No. Do not do this! This is not even close to how to use awk. It is the way someone who had never seen an awk script before might think to try to solve the problem. See any of the other answers for a better approach.

Comment: @EdMorton Hi, I'm not clear about the caveats using getline, can you help to explain? And as to your application suggestion in [link](http://awk.info/?tip/getline), I think this will not meet the caveats: `awk '/^START HELLO/{print;getline;while(1)if ($0 ~/^START STACK/) exit; else {print;getline}}' input.txt`

Comment: A couple of examples: Try modifying your script to print every line containing "foo" to stderr for debugging. Notice that for such a trivial enhancement you need to add the same test in 3 different places or re-write your script, unlike all of the non-getline solutions where it's a trivial tweak in 1 place. What would happen if your input file got zapped while your script was running? Your script would spin off into an infinite loop unlike the others which would terminate gracefully. Read and fully understand all of http://awk.info/?tip/getline before using `getline`.